# Using git with WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) shows many files as modified

Tags: windows, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Git on Windows with MINGW. I thought what about using WSL insteat for git. I have installed git on WSL (I am using Debian). If I trype git status he show many files of my project as 'modified' in red color.

What does that mean? If I use git diff I don' see any difference in the files. How can I safe switch to use WSL?

Comment: WSL doesn't affect how git works. Where are the files stored and how were they created? Are you seeing *newline* differences perhaps?

Comment: How was newline handling configured on Windows? When you install Git on Windows you're asked how to handle newlines and a common choice *on Windows* is to use CRLF locally but push with LF. In Linux, the default is leave newlines unchanged as they're assumed they'll always be LF. Perhaps Git on Linux sees the CRLFs and considers that a change but diff is configured to ignore it? Perhaps you pushed with CRLF to a remote and pulling from Windows introduced CRLFs?

Comment: You'll have to provide more information - how are the files shared? Same folder? Or pulling from the same remote? What are the newline handling settings in both environments? If you use separate repos in Linux and Windows, do they override the newline handling settings?

Comment: I do not see any newline differences. I am using the same local folder where the repository is located. I just tried by entering 'git config core.autocrlf true' in the WSL bash and now I do have the same result in WLS and MINGW. I am not so sure if this was the correct safe way?

Comment: Git for Windows and the WSL installation of Git use different locations to store their global settings. If you need the settings to match you can either modify the global settings or apply repository-local settings.

Comment: Ok, I got it, thank you very much!